# How to Hyperlink text inside variable input and print it using jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink

we have a chatbot who prints replies using the jQuery

```
$('<div class="message message-new"><figure class="avatar"><img src="images/icon" /></figure>' + reply + '</div>').appendTo($('.mCSB_container')).addClass('new');
```

Sometimes the reply variable can contain links, and some of them are very long so we have been trying to hyperlink them, we tried to add an `href` to the  source of the replies

But the jQuery just doesn't print it, not even the hyperlink text, it just completely ignored

if the input from the back-end is

```
Hi <a href="www.google.com" click here /a>
```

It just prints "Hi"

Can somebody please guide us on how we can enable hyperlinks by making changes in the source text to the reply variable or any other way

Comment: What you have tried ?

Comment: my input is read from text file with the reply and the link ,i tried adding a a tag along with replies in my text file, hoping when it comes to front end it will get converted to hyper links

Comment: can you send me the example response you are getting from api

Comment: Hi! What can I help you with?<p><a href="www.google.com">google</a></p>

Comment: ok how you are setting this in HTML ? Show me that code

Comment: $('<div class="message message-new"><figure class="avatar"><img src="https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/6422482?v=3&s=400" /></figure>' + reply + '</div>').appendTo($('.mCSB_container')).addClass('new');  reply is the variable to which reply comes

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("button").click(function() {
                reply = 'Hi! What can I help you with?<p><a href="www.google.com">google</a></p> ';
                $('<div class="message message-new"><figure class="avatar"><img src="avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/6422482?v=3&s=400"‌​; /></figure>' + reply + '</div>').appendTo($('.mCSB_container')).addClass('new');

            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <p>Top</p>
    <div class="mCSB_container">
        test
    </div>


    <button>Add New </button>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot will try it out :)

Comment: This is my file working as expected, check what mistake you are doing

Answer (score 0):

```
$('<a>', {
  href: 'mylink.com',
  html: 'mytext'
})
```